# Unknown error when nginx is starting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

when i started and configtest nginx . i got an unknown error below

```
sudo service nginx configtest
nginx: the configuration file /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger helper agent: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error)
```

my configuration file looks like

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;


#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/sarath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.53;
    passenger_ruby /home/sarath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    server {
        listen       81;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

       location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

server {
    listen       8989;
    server_name  XXXXXXXXXX;

    root /home/sarath/ruby_project/rub/public;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;

    location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|images|javascripts|stylesheets|system)/ {
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
  }
}
```

And my output in the browser is :

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

And my application is in ruby on rails tested ok with production environemnt

Comment: Are there any errors in the application logs? This could be an exception on application start up

Comment: no error in applicaiton . i tested with rails s -e production and worked fine .

Comment: I tested with link  http://XXXXXXXXXX:8989  , here  XXXXXXXXXX is the server address

Comment: The error is that Passenger could not be started. This usually happens when there is en exception on application start up. You can add logs to the application start up, and see whether it gets through to the end

Comment: thanks i found the errors by watching the nginx logs. it happened due to permission and secret key . thanks